# How to detect out-of-memory segfaults?

Tags: linux, memory-management, segmentation-fault, out-of-memory

How does one detect whether a segfault is being caused by an out-of-memory condition?

I have a segfault that defies diagnosis by valgrind and duma/efence because it seems to crash those tools themselves (Valgrind "the impossibe happened", duma: "mprotect() failed: Cannot allocate memory" )

The application (Gazebo) simply crashes with a segfault, and a stack trace that doesn't seem to offer many hints as to why.

TLDR: **Is there an easy tool or method to either confirm or rule out the out-of-memory condition is the cause of a segfault?**

(top does not show an inordinate amount of memory use before crash)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Linux, an out-of-memory condition can manifest in one of two ways:

- If overcommit is disabled, a `brk()` or `mmap()` call fails with `ENOMEM`. Shortly thereafter, the application attempts to dereference the NULL pointer returned from `malloc()` and crashes.
- If overcommit is enabled, then the OOM killer kicks in, and kills the process with SIGKILL. A message is left in dmesg.

As such, you can rule out OOMs by checking that strace doesn't show `brk()` or `mmap()` calls failing with `ENOMEM`, and verifying that no OOM killer messages appear in dmesg.

Comment: So if I do a strace -c and see no errors for brk or mmap, it's 100% not an out of memory issue (assuming that dmes shows no OOM killer info)? [edit: typo fix]

Comment: strace is not systrace. But yes, that and check dmesg

Comment: You can use "sysctl vm.overcommit_memory" to see what overcommit policy your kernel is using.  It's probably 0, which is hard to interpret, but worth knowing anyway.  Also, check the strace() log for mremap(), which is what glibc uses when growing the stack.